# react-native get current location

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps, currentlocation

I tried to use react-native-maps and get my current location.
I tried to use not only 'react-native-geolocation-service' and '@react-native-community/geolocation'. 
Map still indicate google HQ maybe in San Francisco.
({"coords": {"accuracy": 20, "altitude": 5, "heading": 0, "latitude": 37.4219983, "longitude": -122.084, "speed": 0}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1577294172000})

How can I load my current location in my android emulator(Pixel_2 & Pixel_3). 
Please answer to me... 
I've been wrestling for over a week...

Below is my packages.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1"
  },



import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback, 
  TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity,
  Keyboard, ScrollView, PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

import MapView, {Marker}  from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
// import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import RNAndroidLocationEnabler from 'react-native-android-location-enabler';

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
      console.log(position);
  },
  (error) => {
      // See error code charts below.
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
  },
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
);


export default class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>


        <MapView

          minZoomLevel={6}
          maxZoomLevel={16}
          // mapType="none"
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{

            // latitude: this.state.location.coords.latitude,
            // longitude: this.state.location.coords.longitude,
            latitude: 37.4219983,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}>


               <Marker
          coordinate={{latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324}}
          title="this is a marker"
          description="this is a marker example"
        />


        </MapView>
        <Text style={styles.SampleHeader}>
             GUDUGUDU ^^  
             </Text>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  SampleHeader: {
    // flex: 3,
    // flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#d9d9d9',
    // width: 90,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
    textAlign: "center",
    // fontFamily: 'Cochin',
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: '300',
    color: 'black',
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },


});
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal with Android emulators. They are using the Google HQ location by default, you have to manually input another location in the settings.

First, you have to click on the three dots at the bottom of the side menu next to the emulator:

[image]

Then go to the location tab:

[image]

You can now change the `Latitude` and `Longitude` to the desired values and hit `SEND` to update the emulator's location.

Comment: I added additional question on the answer list for uploading image.

Answer (score 0):

My emulator user interface in location is not like yours. How can I call that function?

[image: My emulator: Pixel_2]

Comment: That's odd, I've never seen it like this. Are you up to date with your Android Studio version? I see there's a `Set Location` button, I wonder why it's greyed out...

Answer (score 0):

you should first find your initial location through search box.
after you find it click on the map to specify your exact location.
then press "set Location" button